# Send a value of foreach loop form using ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to send value from form to controller but the error that faced me all forms send value as a first form id I want each form to send the data inside it when I press the send button, but what happens is that everyone sends its content based on the first ID of the form;

blade code

```
@forelse($matches as $match)
    <form class="ajaxform">
        @csrf
        <div class="wrapper-new1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="record_one" id="validationCustom18" value="{{$match->record_one}}"  required> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="record_two" id="validationCustom18" value="{{$match->record_two}}"  required> 
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" value="{{$match->id}}" id="validationCustom18" >
        </div>
        <button type="submit" style="margin-top: 4px;" class="btns">تغيير نتيجة المباراة </button>
    </form>
    @empty 
    <div class="alert alert-danger"> لا يوجد مباريات لعرضها الان </div>   
@endforelse
```

ajax code

```
$('.btns').on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  
    let record_one = $("input[name=record_one]").val();
    let record_two = $("input[name=record_two]").val();
    let id = $("input[name=id]").val();
    let _token   = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
  
    $.ajax({
        url: "/admin/team/matchesList/"+id+"",
        type:"POST",
        data:{
            record_one:record_one,
            record_two:record_two,
            id :id,
            _token: _token
        },
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response) {
                $('.success').text(response.success);
                $(".ajaxform")[0].reset();
            }
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.btns').on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        let form = $(this).closest('.ajaxform');
        let record_one = form.find("input[name=record_one]").val();
        let record_two = form.find("input[name=record_two]").val();
        let id = form.find("input[name=id]").val();
        let _token   = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
  
        $.ajax({
          url: "/admin/team/matchesList/"+id+"",
          type:"POST",
          data:{
            record_one:record_one,
            record_two:record_two,
            id :id,
            _token: _token
          },
          formElement:form,
          success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response) {
              $('.success').text(response.success);
              this.formElement[0].reset();
            }
          },
         });
    });
```